# Symfony 3 validation expression not evaluated

Tags: validation, symfony

My form is tied to its model with constraints set up. Validation pass gracefully when values comply to constraints and vis versa …
**Except** for only one field decorated with an Expression constraint which seems to never be evaluated.

My need is: *If my model's "helpType" property value **is not** contained in some array, **do not pass** validation* so I expected the following code to work:

`// PostModel.php`

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.isValidHelpType()",
 *     message="post.create.help-invalid"
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $helpType;
public function isValidHelpType()
{
    return in_array($this->getHelpType(), Post::getHelpTypes());
}
```

`// PostType.php`

```
// …
->add( 'helpType', TextType::class, [ 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label'=>false ])
// …
```

The constraints seems to never get executed since whenever I put `"false"` in place of the expression, or `die;` from inside the *isValidHelpType()* function (before return statement, obviously) nothing happens.

Is there some kind of distinct type of constraints like `class` level versus `property` level with XOR behaviour ? Anyway, any idea of what's going on here ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm using validation groups, I simply forgot to put the `group={"some_group"}` property on that constraint, relevant to the execution context.

In the end, here is what I ended up in order to make sure a (integer) value is contained in some array:

```
<?php
// ...
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.isHelpTypeValid()",
 *     message="create.help-invalid",
 *     groups={"creation"}
 * )
 * @ ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $helpType;
public function isHelpTypeValid()
{
    // value from POST are strings, now make sure it looks like numeric
    return is_numeric($this->getHelpType())
        // Cast to integer and set value
        && $this->setHelpType((int)$this->getHelpType())
        // now test if reference array contains that value
        && in_array($this->getHelpType(), Post::getHelpTypes(), true );
}
```